# trying to insert a blank page in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I'm trying to insert a blank page as the last page of some chapters. For instance, I want a blank page after the cover page. I'm doing it like this:

```
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="cover_pagemaster" force-page-count="even">
       <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="cover" page-position="any" />
           <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="empty_page" page-position="last" blank-or-not-blank="blank" />
       </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
```

It should be two pages, one with the cover and one blank. Why doesnt it work that way?

Thanx for help!

EDIT:

```
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="cover_pagemaster" force-page-count="even">
           <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="empty_page" page-position="last" blank-or-not-blank="blank" />
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="cover" page-position="first" />
           </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
```

Well, I tried different combinations now and it still doesnt work. Not even the force-page-count works (I'm using the evaluation version of Antenna House).

I just cant find a working example of xsl-fo code that produces a blank page as the second page of a two-page page-master.

2nd EDIT:

```
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="cover" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
       <fo:region-body />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="empty_page">
       <fo:region-body />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
```

and then in the page-sequence:

```
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="cover_pagemaster">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
       <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="70mm" left="30mm">
          <fo:block>
             <fo:external-graphic src="coverpage.png" content-width="140mm" content-height="90mm" />
          </fo:block>
       </fo:block-container>
       <fo:block-container text-align="right" hyphenate="true" absolute-position="absolute" font-family="Calibri" font-size="4em" top="200mm" left="42mm" margin-right="10mm">
          <fo:block>COVERPAGE</fo:block>
          <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
          <fo:block>ABSOLUTE POSITIONING
          </fo:block>
       </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
 </fo:page-sequence
```

Comment: In the force-page-count attribute you must use "end-on-even" instead of "even".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of repeatable-page-master-alternatives is processed in order. So when the formatter processes the last page of a chapter, it will go through the list, and it will see that the condition for the first entry (page-position="any") is valid for this page. so the last page gets assigned "cover" without checking the full list of alternatives.
So you should build the list of repeatable-page-master-alternatives to have the exceptions (first page, last page) listed before the more common pages (left, right, any).

**Edit**:

Now they're in the correct order. But you've specified `blank-or-not-blank="blank"`. This means "only use this master page if the page is blank (i.e. contains no body text)".
What does the second page currently look like? Which master page gets used?

**Edit 2**:
In the force-page-count attribute you must use "end-on-even" instead of "even".

Comment: I meant what happens in the output? Does the page after the cover belong to the cover_pagemaster page-sequence, and if so, which master-page alternative does it choose?

Comment: It worked now! Thanx a lot! Additionally to the fact that I didnt use end-on-even, I didnt understand that the "even" and "odd" where counted for the entire document. I though that with every page-sequence-master, the counting starts new.